# Nightwatch Module Test Example

Tags: nightwatch.js

I want to write all tests in module and import into a main test js file for execution. How to achieve this? Below is my code snippet.

```
module.exports = (function(settings) {
    settings.test_workers = false;

    return settings;
})(require('./nightwatch.json'));

var testPage = (require('./test.js'));

var myTest;
module.exports = {       
      myTest = new testPage(browser)
      myTest.Login(browser)   -> Giving error on this line. 
}
```

Test.js

```
module.exports = {    
    'Login' : function Login (browser) {
      browser
        .url('http://localhost:63916/Login/Login')
        .useXpath()
        .maximizeWindow()
        .pause(3000)
}
```

Why giving this error? Thanks.

Comment: What is the error saying?

Comment: (property) myTest: undefined errors message display when i hover it.

Comment: Is that true that you want to reuse the test.js ?For example : several cases (login with correct credentials ; login with wrong email ; login with wrong password ) are similar and you want to group them.

Comment: Yes, I want to reuse Login function in maintest.js.